# Cat one .csv file with all other files in directory

Tags: linux, csv, cat

I have multiple csv files that each needs header data placing in row 1, from a seperate csv file which is 1 line in length. The file is called Anon_student_ID, and every other file in the directory needs this data as line 1 while retaining it's file name.

I am trying to use the cat function from the command line.

My attempted to solution was - `$ cat Anon_student_ID.csv *.csv > *.csv`

However, I get `bash: *.csv: ambiguous redirect`,

Could someone explain why it isn't taking the second filename and using it as the output file name? And what would be a better way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s extglob
TEMP=$(mktemp)
IFS= read -r HEADER < Anon_student_ID.csv
for CSV in !(Anon_student_ID).csv; do
    { echo "$HEADER"; cat "$CSV"; } > "$TEMP" && cat "$TEMP" > "$CSV"
done
rm -f "$TEMP"
```

- `nullglob` prevents patterns from presenting themselves when no match is found.
- `extglob` enables extended patterns like `!(...)`.
- `!(Anon_student_ID).csv` matches all CSV files not having the filename `Anon_student_ID`.
- `sed` is good but it will look hacky on this. It would require repeated reading of the header file as well.

If files are not that big, using an array for a buffer instead of a temporary file would be good too:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s extglob
[[ BASH_VERSINFO -ge 4 ]] || exit 1  ## Make sure we have `readarray`
IFS= read -r HEADER < Anon_student_ID.csv
for CSV in !(Anon_student_ID).csv; do
    readarray -t LINES < "$CSV"
    printf '%s\n' "$HEADER" "${LINES[@]}" > "$CSV"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this works excellently and it taught me lots of new tricks with bash. It's still new to me but I'm getting there.

For arrays, what's the upper limit of a file size you would say an array could handle?

Answer (score 1):

As a one-liner:

```
mv Anon_student_ID.csv Anon_student_ID; for i in *.csv; do cat Anon_student_ID > tmpfile; cat ${i} >> tmpfile; mv tmpfile ${i}; done; mv Anon_student_ID Anon_student_ID.csv
```

In a readable format:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv Anon_student_ID.csv Anon_student_ID
for i in *.csv; do 
    cat Anon_student_ID > tmpfile
    cat ${i} >> tmpfile
    mv tmpfile ${i}
done
mv Anon_student_ID Anon_student_ID.csv
```

Anon_student_ID is renamed, so it will not be used for appending itself to itself, since it would match `*.csv`, too.